# How to store AngularFireList observable into array in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I am retrieving data from Firebase using AngularFire2. I have difficulty with storing the observable that is returned into an array. I want to use that array for filtering later.

I use a provider to get data:

```
import { AngularFireList, AngularFireDatabase } from 
'angularfire2/database'; //*
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'; //*


@Injectable()
export class CrudProvider {

public storeList: AngularFireList<any>; //*

constructor(
public afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase //*
  ) {
this.storeList = this.afDatabase.list('/stores/'); //*
  }

  getStores(): AngularFireList<any> {     //*
    return this.storeList;                //*
  }                                       //*

}
```

I import the provider and do more operations on the page to display the data.

search.html:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-searchbar (ioninput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let store of storeList | async">
            <p>{{store?.name}}</p>
            <p>{{store?.description}}</p>
            <p>{{store?.city}}</p>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

search.ts:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';             //*
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { CrudProvider } from '../../providers/crud/crud';  //*
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-search',
  templateUrl: 'search.html',
})
export class SearchPage {

public storeList: Observable<any>;                          //*
stores: any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public crud: CrudProvider                               //*
  ) { 
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {


    this.stores=[];

    this.storeList = this.crud.getStores().valueChanges();    //*

 this.storeList.subscribe(store => this.stores.push(store));

    console.log(this.stores);

  }
}
```

The query works successfully and shows data from database on the screen.

The problem is when I try to store the Observable storeList into the stores array. console.log(this.stores) shows an empty array! Therefore, the code above is not working.

The reason that I would like to use an array is that I want to implement a filter using entries from search bar. Observable has not worked well. I want to try it with an array.

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `this.storeList.subscribe(...)` is an asynchronous call and has not been completed when you do `console.log(this.stores);`. That is why its an empty array (set by `this.stores = [];`) . Filtering with Observables is perfectly possible and many good examples are available

Comment: Your code _is_ working, you're just logging `stores` before it's being updated. Put the log inside the subscription and you'll see. `this.storeList.subscribe(store => { this.stores.push(store); console.log(this.stores); });`